# Oracle Warehouse Builder stand alone doesn't work

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-warehouse-builder

i have Oracle Database 11g Enreprise edition Release 11.2.0.1.0, i'm in windows 64bit so i can't use the Design Center, so i downloaded Oracle Warehouse Builder Stanalone version 11.2.0.3.0 .

I created a database and unlocked the owbsys account, and i started a listener in the database, then in the Warehouse builder i started the respository assistant to create a new workspace, but when i have to put username and passwword of a database administrator ("system", 123), or another (user,password) of the database , i have the following error:

```
    ORA-12523 : TNS:listener could not find instance appropriate or the 
    client connection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No body answered my question, but i finally found out the reason why, if we want to use oracle warehouse builder standalone version, we must follow the configuration steps that we can find in oracle website.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/owb.112/e17130/setup_windows.htm#WBINS26365